# How are wordpress standards used in Timber

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, timber

Not being a PHP dev but having used Twig before I really liked the idea of using Timber and Twig to develop a theme.

There are however a few unanswered questions I have from reading the documentation. This revolves mostly around **wp_head**, **wp_footer** and **wp_enqueue**.

Everything I read about theming in WP is adamant that we call on the first two functions in our theme and that we enqueue all scripts and styles.

I assume that plugins for example might hook into this functionality to enable their own scripts.

How *Timber* handles this is very unclear to me however. In an unofficial tutorial I read this:

> the first thing we're doing is fetching the context of the theme with `Timber::get_context()`;. This object will contain such things as your menus, wp_head, and wp_footer

So the context is handling this for us already? I guess I still need to tell it where to render the scripts and styles, right? How?

In the official documentation:

> For example, if you need to call `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`, you’d do
>   it like this

If I need to, well yeah you always need to right, ....right?

So when I look at the *timber starter theme* it does call this function in it's `html-header.twig` but it also imports a stylesheet without enqueuing.

And then there is the `header.php` in the starter theme. Which I assume should never be called. Here are the comments there.

> Third party plugins that hijack the theme will call `wp_head()` to get the header template.

Is this just a typo or something? wp_head doesn't return the header template, get_header does. Am I incorrect?

Let's assume it should say get_header. I don't understand the implications this will have if I use something like woocommerce. Is the documentation for woocommerce enough and I can just include this in my theme and it will work? Why isn't this explained better in the woocommerce part of the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me myself find Timber starter theme a bit confusing too and additionally I am not a fan of few solutions which are in there (short side note: that's why I wrote my own Timber starter theme).

In general you are right.

It is enough that `wp_head` and `wp_footer` are loaded from Twig files and yes - we have to always call those functions in our themes.

Why they do not enqueue style file but reference it directly? Maybe it is just simply to not make the theme more complex(??) although definitely it's not a best practice as of today.

And yes - `wp_head()` hijacking is definitely a typo and they meant `get_header()`.

Comment: Is your starter theme publicly available?

Comment: I am releasing it next week. At the moment wrapping up documentation pages and then I need around 1-2 days of feature development / fixes. I hope it will be ready by Wednesday. You can check docs here (still obviously in progress) https://github.com/LowGravityPL/RaccoonWP.github.io